# Handling cases that won't occur in tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, uitableview

I'm implementing logic for returning specific cells in a table view call. What suggestions exist for covering the "default" case, if I'm using a switch statement?

See example here:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0: // CompanyDetailsGeneralTableViewCell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CompanyDetailsGeneral", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CompanyDetailsGeneralTableViewCell

        // STUFF FOR CompanyDetailsGeneralTableViewCell

        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CompanyResources", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CompanyResourcesTableViewCell

        return cell
    default:
        // Can't reach here (never!) as table has only 2 sections.
        return UITableViewCell() // Hack. BEST PRACTICE?
    }
}
```

Among the approaches I've considered:

- Not using the switch at all, but it seems more structurally fitting for a switch.
- Throwing a runtime exception. Not possible as runtime exceptions are not exciting in Swift.
- returning nil - Can't do that, as this function does not return an optional.

Would appreciate comments and feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call terminating functions like `assertionFailure()`, `preconditionFailure()` or `fatalError("Unexpected section in TableView")` in order to terminate the application in that scenario.

Comment: Thank You !

fatalError("Unexpected section \\(indexPath.section) in TableView") it is.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing that you do. It may not display anything but at least the app won't crash which is important to users.